# Separating floats, ints, negatives and strings that contain letters and numbers and .'s in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, loops

I currently have a list of strings that I iterate through..

```
string1 = 'CRUC1AL 34 6 5 0 23 75.6 11 89.6 3 1.39 robiin 40 15 8 2 26 78.0 14 89.5 4 1.36 Surreal 31 14 6 2 25 68.3 6 79.8 2 1.17 MiGHTYMAX 24 8 7 2 26 78.0 -2 57.5 -2 1.02 Thomas 25 17 10 3 28 70.7 -3 77.8 -2 0.95'
string2 = 'Lucky 27 6 8 4 27 68.3 0 71.0 4 1.01 kiR 27 18 6 0 36 58.5 -9 77.6 1 0.92 kwezz 29 11 6 2 32 53.7 -3 77.2 -1 0.91 scott 20 6 5 2 26 56.1 -6 50.0 -2 0.75 cleMeNz0 25 15 5 3 33 48.8 -8 71.9 -7 0.74'
```

I replace all off the ","s with " " so I can iterate through them all. Now I need to be able to put the names into 1 list and the numbers. The names contain letters, numbers, punctuation, and dashes..

```
player_names1 = []
player_names2 = []
team1_list = []
team2_list = []
for i in string1:
    if i.isalpha() or i.endswith('.') or i.isupper():
        player_names1.append(i)
    elif not i.isalpha() and not i.endswith('.') and not i.isupper():
        team1_list.append(i)

for i in string2:
    if i.isalpha() or i.endswith('.') or i.isupper():
        player_names2.append(i)
    elif not i.isalpha() and not i.endswith('.') and not i.isupper():
        team2_list.append(i)
```

I've considered using an index or find function, but I don't want to have to make a new and not sequence to my if statements in order to do this..
This way worked to fix the one name with a . in a previous string and getting CRUC1AL into the names list, but now there is one with a 0 at the end and it's trying to append it into my stats list. I also tried..

```
if not i.isdigit() and not i.startswith('-'):
    player_names1.append(i)
    print(i)
    #= CRUC1AL 75.6 89.6 1.39
else:
    team1_list.append(i)
```

But this appended the floats and player names together. I've tried searching for the fix but there isn't anything specific that I have been able to find that can separate float values... so in all I need to be able to separate the floats, ints, and negative numbers from the names that might have -'s, .'s, and letters. Any suggestions? Full code that produces the error found [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/1O0WgeZe).. Also any tips on writing my code more elegantly would be great!

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. How is pandas related to your question? Please show a sample of the expected output.

Comment: Where does that data comes from? Have you noticed that it follows a pattern?

Comment: @DYZ 94,50,20,6,78,388.4,16,386.6,10,6.07,16 is a sample output. I take the values, can make a dictionary with the names and stats of each player, then i can just take the sum of their stats and write them to a CSV file for analysis. The data for the issue I'm running into comes from 'https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches/mapstatsid/98497/endpoint-vs-fakemaquinas'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split over the spaces and append to the corresponding list.

```
player_names1 = []
team1_list = []
for idx, el in  enumerate(string1.split()):
   if idx % 11 == 0:
      player_names1.append(el)
   else:
      team1_list.append(el)
```

Another way might be to build a dataframe with the results.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.array(string1.split()).reshape(5,11))
           0   1   2   3  4   5     6   7     8   9    10
0    CRUC1AL  34   6   5  0  23  75.6  11  89.6   3  1.39
1     robiin  40  15   8  2  26  78.0  14  89.5   4  1.36
2    Surreal  31  14   6  2  25  68.3   6  79.8   2  1.17
3  MiGHTYMAX  24   8   7  2  26  78.0  -2  57.5  -2  1.02
4     Thomas  25  17  10  3  28  70.7  -3  77.8  -2  0.95
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I guess it is treating the strings as a list object so they can't be split. I'll attempt the dataframe style.

Comment: string1 is a string (the string you posted in your example), not a list

Comment: I edited my code to line up with yours and now I am receiving ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'CRUC1AL', because later in the code I am making a separate list elements. But just converting it straight into a dataframe did work so I will be able to manipulate how I want to use the stats. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data appears to be following a pattern:

`[name] [int] [int] [int] [int] [int] [float] [int] [float] [int] [float]`

**Assuming that your goal is to split the data, that is you're not doing this purely to learn**, we can take advantage of this pattern.

Like @abc I chose to use Pandas, I think it makes sense for this kind of data, and it means we don't have to manually cast each value to the appropriate type.

```py
import pandas as pd

team_1_str = 'CRUC1AL 34 6 5 0 23 75.6 11 89.6 3 1.39 robiin 40 15 8 2 26 78.0 14 89.5 4 1.36 Surreal 31 14 6 2 25 68.3 6 79.8 2 1.17 MiGHTYMAX 24 8 7 2 26 78.0 -2 57.5 -2 1.02 Thomas 25 17 10 3 28 70.7 -3 77.8 -2 0.95'
team_2_str = 'Lucky 27 6 8 4 27 68.3 0 71.0 4 1.01 kiR 27 18 6 0 36 58.5 -9 77.6 1 0.92 kwezz 29 11 6 2 32 53.7 -3 77.2 -1 0.91 scott 20 6 5 2 26 56.1 -6 50.0 -2 0.75 cleMeNz0 25 15 5 3 33 48.8 -8 71.9 -7 0.74'

team_1_split = team_1_str.split()
team_2_split = team_2_str.split()

team_1_data = (team_1_split[i:i + 11] for i in range(0, len(team_1_split), 11))
team_2_data = (team_2_split[i:i + 11] for i in range(0, len(team_2_split), 11))

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=team_1_data)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=team_2_data)

print(df_1, end='\n\n')
print(df_2)
```

Output:

```
           0   1   2   3  4   5     6   7     8   9    10
0    CRUC1AL  34   6   5  0  23  75.6  11  89.6   3  1.39
1     robiin  40  15   8  2  26  78.0  14  89.5   4  1.36
2    Surreal  31  14   6  2  25  68.3   6  79.8   2  1.17
3  MiGHTYMAX  24   8   7  2  26  78.0  -2  57.5  -2  1.02
4     Thomas  25  17  10  3  28  70.7  -3  77.8  -2  0.95

          0   1   2  3  4   5     6   7     8   9    10
0     Lucky  27   6  8  4  27  68.3   0  71.0   4  1.01
1       kiR  27  18  6  0  36  58.5  -9  77.6   1  0.92
2     kwezz  29  11  6  2  32  53.7  -3  77.2  -1  0.91
3     scott  20   6  5  2  26  56.1  -6  50.0  -2  0.75
4  cleMeNz0  25  15  5  3  33  48.8  -8  71.9  -7  0.74
```

Comment: Tried this and got the error.. TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable.. I am going to try to convert the apparent list into a string then run this into the code to see if I can get the same results. Will post back when I get the chance.